# What happens if you import a module twice, once in the top-level script, and once in one of the modules import by the top-level script?

Tags: python, import, module, random-seed

As the title says, what happens if you import a module twice, once in the top-level script, and once in one of the modules import by the top-level script?

The reason I ask is because I wonder if fixing a random seed at the top-level script is enough, or I have to do the same in every module that uses the random package.

Comment: Python modules are only imported once at runtime. Any initialization of global variables, etc. that occurs at the module level will only be run once during the first import.

Comment: It is pretty much the same as importing the module twice, or any number of times, in your top level script, or anywhere else. It will only load once.